# When to pray nafl prayers?

Tags: salat, fiqh, nafl

Salam

I want to know when can one pray nafl prayers? Can I pray some nafl immediately after say Zuhr, Maghrib and Isha? Or can we pray nafl anytime apart from the forbidden times? Are they always done in two Rakats? So would I do 2 rakats finish them start another 2 finish them and keep going till I want to stop?

Comment: This question needs more information: what you mean by nafl, if you want a the view of a specific school of jurisprudence you should name it. In general anything beyond the 5 obligatory prayer is nafl or sunnah any differentiation between both has its basis in fiqh schools and there terminology. And how to perform them is also discussed among scholars.

Comment: I don’t really follow a particular school. I’ve been taught to pray the hanafi way but I know they say ‘rabbigfirli rabbigfirli’ in between the two prostrations but I do. I don’t really know much about any of the madhabs and I don’t have anyone to teach me on the schools  I read on another site it isn’t compulsory to follow a school. 

I should of been more clear just regular nafls just say I have free time and would like to pray extra salahs

Comment: I pray the sunnahs eg 2 before fajr 4 before zhur 2 after 2 after Maghrib etc